# c# how can i display all item on combobox when key press on?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want to display the items of `combox`
when I press a akey on keyboard

how I can display all items on combobox when I press key 
I want to do that when I click enter key

then combobox item display like this image

[image]

```
private void comboBox4_KeyPress(object sender, EventArgs e){
   if(e.Keychar==(char)consoleKey.Enter){
       displayAllitems();
       //like the image
   }
}
```

Comment: Just set `DroppedDown = true;` on the combobox you want to expand

Comment: Is it a webforms control or another thing?